# Creating a method to submit a form without duplicating code in multiple controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Folks, I'm looking for a solution to avoid duplication when I make the same method Post for a several controllers

Can you tell me a solution how to make a method with sending a form that I can use in any controller and return a model with an error?

I have several Controllers in which I will have a form sending (in the real project it is a service with email sending). On showed it in the screenshots and code.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

```
public class AdditionalController : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ScheduleDemo(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Content("The Best");
        }

        return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/Partial/ScheduleDemo.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

```
ASPX 
HomeController Index.cshtml

<h1>Home</h1>
@await Html.PartialAsync("Partial/ScheduleDemo")

ASPX 
AdditionalController Index.cshtml

<h1>Additional</h1>
@await Html.PartialAsync("Partial/ScheduleDemo")
```

```
I did not create a view for the BaseController in ScheduleDemo, but use a partial view

ASPX 
ScheduleDemo.cshtml
@model UserModel

<form asp-controller="Base" asp-action="ScheduleDemo" method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
    <p>
        <label asp-for="@Model.UserName">UserName</label><br />
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.UserName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName"  class="text-danger" style="color: red;"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label asp-for="@Model.Age">Age</label><br />
        <input asp-for="@Model.Age" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger" style="color: red;"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label asp-for="@Model.City">City</label><br />
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.City" />
        
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

[additional url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG6ik.png)
[base url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Iyt.png)

In order to avoid code duplication, I tried to make BaseController and define this form sending in it, but when I make a post I go to another route localhost://Base/... and I need to stay at the same url, for example localhost://Aditional/... The biggest problem is not in that url, when I send a form successfully, everything is OK, the problem is when ModelState.IsValid == false... then model returns to me, but the page says that View by this url does not exist or in my case redirect to PartialView and it is logical, because I send form from parent controller...

Comment: [I have tried by using your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZhN.png). And not find the error about ` the page says that View by this url does not exist`.

Comment: I described that I did, I already had so many options, just horror.

The idea is that I need to make a component (it should be post) that I can use in all controllers.

For example I have a sending form, now I need to add it to a Post controller, and tomorrow there will be another controller and I need to add it there.

Comment: Could you please share more information as the issue has not been reproduced in both scenarios, I haven't got `View by this url does not exist ` this error message. In addition, could you please share your expectation as well.

Comment: You might want to check on ActionFilterAttribute to validate your model state. You can override OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted. Then use the ActionFilterAttribute in HomeController and AdditionalController. From the BaseController, you can define property getter and setter for your model. Then access and validate this model inside the class where you override the OnActionExecuting.